# Asking for old-ish questions from SuperUser

Tags: discussion

After stumbling upon (and answering) two questions on SuperUser which would have a much happier life here ([1](https://superuser.com/questions/880393/munin-supersampling-data-consolidation-graph),[2](https://superuser.com/questions/758915/puppet-file-line-remove-line-with-unknown-number-of-whitespaces)), I have raised a moderator flag asking for the questions' migration to SF.

The migration request has been declined due to the questions' age. Apparently, SuperUser has a moderator policy of not migrating questions older than two months.

Would it make sense to place an "official" request in the SuperUser Meta to allow for migrations of this kind if we explicitly ask for them? If so, what would a sensible procedure look like? For starters, we might discuss each migration candidate in SF Meta first to see if the majority agrees that it is a good fit and just raise a moderator flag referring to our meta post. This is rather heavyweight, but would prevent annoying SU moderators with migration requests of questions which would get closed here afterwards.

The rationale behind all this is increasing SF's weight in relevant areas through the aggregation of interesting content. People *still* asking on SuperUser about Puppet manifests and Munin plugin configurations might be a sign that we are not perceived as the right place to go for this kind of questions. And apparently SU moderation is either unable to tell these questions are on topic here or is too put off by our *"we don't want (SU) crap here"* policy to even try migrating these questions. Speaking of which, are we even on the migration target list over at SU's?

Comment: Yes, SF is on SU's migration target list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a SU moderation policy, but a [network-wide feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) and can't be changed per site: Questions older than 60 days can't be migrated, period ([another meta.se discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days)).

Comment: The network-wide feature is that *users* cannot vote for migration if a question is older than 60 days. The SU policy is that *moderators* won't migrate questions older than 2 months. This might get out of hand and become yet another discussion about the SF's direction, but I strongly disagree that there is no value in migrating relevant questions. If it is our area of expertise and we want to answer these questions (while the originating site can't), then they belong here.

Comment: No. Even mod's can't migrate stuff older than 60 days. [Citing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work): `Only questions which are less than 60 days old can be migrated. This rule even applies to moderators. Developers are able to bypass this restriction, but they only do so in very, very rare cases.`

Comment: Bummer. I see. Too bad.

Comment: As a SU mod, I can confirm that.

Answer (score 3):

As noted elsewhere, there's a 60-day age restriction on these migrations. This was implemented after a great deal of irritation was caused by folks carelessly shuffling well-regarded, on-topic posts between sites.

That said, it is always possible to make exceptions to rules like this. However, if the questions are not *off-topic* on the site where they were asked, I would be reluctant to move them - it tends to accomplish little and confuse much.

Nothing stops you from *re-asking* a question here that has been asked elsewhere though. If it is a good question, and on-topic, then addressing it to a new audience can benefit *both* sites.

Comment: What do you mean by re-asking? Would I be copying the off-site question's content to SF under my name and attributing it to the other site? This is really encouraged?

Comment: "Encouraged"? Not really; it is rarely a good idea. In this particular instance, it beats migration if you want SF answers to a SU question though.